# Codeigniter SQL Returning Repeating Identical Object Array

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, codeigniter

For some reason in Codeigniter, my SQL query is returning repeated replicates of the Object Array based on the number of rows. The weird thing is that my if I put my SQL query directly into phpMyAdmin, it is returning the correct results - and I should add that the code is nearly identical to another call function I have which works normally.

Am I just blind after staring at my code for so long?!

***UPDATE:*** Just a side note, I haven't included my code for manipulation of the $query because my SQL result is already wrong.

**Result**

```
CI_DB_mysqli_result Object

(
    [conn_id] => mysqli Object
    (
        // Information
            (
            )

        //Information
    )

[result_id] => mysqli_result Object
    (
        [current_field] => 0
        [field_count] => 4
        [lengths] => 
        [num_rows] => 2
        [type] => 0
    )

[result_array] => Array
    (
    )

[result_object] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1594
                [user_id] => 102
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1279
                [user_id] => 102
            )
    )

[custom_result_object] => Array
    (
    )

[current_row] => 0
[num_rows] => 
[row_data] => 
)
1

CI_DB_mysqli_result Object
(
    [conn_id] => mysqli Object
    (
        // Information
            (
            )

        //Information
    )

[result_id] => mysqli_result Object
    (
        [current_field] => 0
        [field_count] => 4
        [lengths] => 
        [num_rows] => 2
        [type] => 0
    )


[result_array] => Array
    (
    )

[result_object] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1594
                [user_id] => 102
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1279
                [user_id] => 102
            )


    )

[custom_result_object] => Array
    (
    )

[current_row] => 0
[num_rows] => 
[row_data] => 
)
1
```

**Code**

```
function data($update_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query('
        SELECT * 
        FROM `list` 
        JOIN `tasks` ON list.id = tasks.list_id
        WHERE (tasks.date < \' 2016-03-19 \' AND tasks.list_id = '$update_id') 
        ORDER BY `tasks`.`date` DESC
        ');
        return $query;
    }
```

And I get the result above. There isn't even a loop in my code, so I don't understand where the loop would come from...

I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: if i understand you correctly you get your results twice isn't it ?
In this case its pretty much clear your controller calls this function twice or get called twice

Comment: How are you getting what you are showing in **Result**? Is that a var_dump of `$query`?

Comment: The controller simply calls it using $result = $this->mdl_lists->data($update_id); and then simply print_r($result)

Comment: Yeah, I might rewrite the controller function again from scratch and hopefully it will solve the problem. Thanks for having a look at it and re-affirming that it wasn't the query that was messing me up.

Answer (score 0):

use return $query->result(); instead of return $query

Comment: Yes, I know I have to loop it through result() to get the final result. However because it is returning two object arrays, my $query->result() is not working as normal. So I haven't included my manipulation of the $query because my SQL result is already wrong.

Comment: try return $query->row() or return $query->array_result()

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting my issue. I'm not asking how to manipulate the incorrect result, I'm asking why I'm getting the incorrect result to begin with and how to correct it. I'm sure there are ways to manipulate it to make it work, but it doesn't fix the root problem.